# Android WebView doesn't load jQuery

Tags: jquery, android, webview

I'm making a webapp and I'm using jQuery.

I've made a simple android application with a WebView in it, and I load my url: www.mydomain.com

In mydomain.com I have:

```
<script src="js/jquery_1.4.2_min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("Hii!!!!");
});
</script>
```

If I visit mydomain from the browser, the alert shows fine. But If I visit from my native application, it doesn't show. What can I do?

Comment: Yes. It is loaded. Ive edited the code. It works fine in browser but not from app.

Comment: what is a web app? like mobile.mydomain.com?

Comment: does it work even if you dont use jQuery and just do a plain ol' alert?

Comment: Neal Im trying with a simple: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  alert("juas");
 </script>` and it doesnt work...

Comment: Ive just put browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); before browser.setWebViewClient and it works... :) thanks!

Comment: @Klian : have you got any solution? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is JavaScript enabled in your webview...?

```
WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: yes

    `browser = new WebView(this);
    
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    .....
    
    setContentView(browser);
      
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl("http://mydomain.com");`

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but thought i'd add my 2cents anyway.

Javascript alerts do work in a webview, but you have to set the Web chrome client first.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer for me

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert with Android native but we have just developed an app using jQuery based site within a webview. You need setJavaScriptEnabled(true) in your activity class and jQuery runs jsut fine. However your example with alert('Hi'); will not work because Android webviews don't support alerts by default. It can be enabled with a little googling... http://lexandera.com/2009/01/adding-alert-support-to-a-webview/

Alternatively we added a custom showAlert js function to display pretty user notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Where is your js/jquery_1.4.2_min.js script located? If it is located in your assets directory, then you should initialize the webView giving it the assets directory as baseUrl:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

or

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

You could try to create a simple .js file with a simple function like

```
function dummy(document) { document.write("Hooray it works"); }
```

and try to access the *dummy* function in your html to test if the .js file is included.

Answer (score 3):

You may need two things:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the location of the jquery.js file. Post some code about how you are setting up the webView. That would give us some hints.

For an example, look at this:
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: Create a Main Activity.

```
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       private WebView webView;
        private JavaScriptInterFace javaScriptInterFace;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    javaScriptInterFace=new JavaScriptInterFace(this);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(javaScriptInterFace, "AndroidFunction");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

   }



      }
```

Create another java file named JavaScriptInterFace

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
      import android.widget.Toast;

        public class JavaScriptInterFace {
 Context mContext;

 JavaScriptInterFace(Context c) {
     mContext = c;
             }

 public int changeImage(){
    Log.e("Got", "it"+2); 
     return 2;
 }

 public void showToast(){
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

     }
```

the creat a html file put this one in project's asset folder

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
         <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
       <title>My HTML</title>
      </head>
        <body>
         <p id="mytext">Hello!</p>
             <img alt="show" src="ic_left_arrow.png" id="myImage"/>
           </br>
           <input type="button" value="Change" onClick="changeImage()" />
           <input type="button" value="Show tost" onClick="showToast()" />

           <script language="javascript">
             function changeImage() {
               i=AndroidFunction.changeImage();
            if(i===2){
           document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = i;
           document.getElementById('myImage').src="ic_right_arrow.png";
        }
           }
          function showToast() {
              AndroidFunction.showToast();
          }

         </script>

           </body>
            </html>
```

Put the required images in asset folder of your project along with the above html file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct sequence-

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xxx.html");

By mistake dont put your invocation sequence go wrong like below

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xxx.html");
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);