# JQuery doesn't work on WebView

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, android-2.2-froyo

I tried to include JQuery files in assets/scripts and on Internet, but the alert dialog doesn't show. I got the log output and make it output.html, it works in Windows (so strange!).
What's the problem with WebView?

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final String s = "<html><head>" +
    "<link href=\"css/my.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />" +
    "<script src=\"scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
    "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
    "<script>" +
    "$(document).ready(function(){ alert('hello'); });" +
    "</script>" +
    "</head><body><div>All I hear is raindrops." +
    "Falling on the rooftop. Oh baby tell me why you have to go. " +
    "Cause this pain I feel you won't go away. And today, " +
    "I'm officially missing you.</div></body></html>";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Log.d("Something", s);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

This is the log output after adding extension ".html". It works on Firefox but does not on WebView. :(

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/my.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ alert('hello'); });</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    All I hear is raindrops.Falling on the rooftop. Oh baby tell me why you have to go. Cause this pain I feel you won't go away. And today, I'm officially missing you.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve it ? I am facing this problem now. What can I do? :(

Answer (score 7):

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

be change to

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(getAssets(), s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

to get asset file, you will need to access app's asset path. An app is an user on Android, so cannot access path begin with "file://" directory.

Comment: Error :), wrong parameter getAssets in loadDataWithBaseUrl();

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have the jquery.js file in your assets/scripts folder for this to work.

*scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js*

That should work.

Comment: I just check it with the exact same code, and it works. Are you sure you saved it with the proper file name? Or may be if you want to pick it up from the web, try adding the INTERNET permission, that also works.

Comment: @Emerald214 doesn't work for me either, I commented out the CSS line and I have a jquery.min.js file in my root assets folder   using Android 3.0 on a 3.1 device

Answer (score 2):

`setPluginsEnabled` in `WebView` settings to `true`.

Comment: Can you include some sample code?  I don't see a "setPluginsEnabled" function anywhere related to WebView

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned on [Android WebView doesn't load jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750657/android-webview-doesnt-load-jquery/11817491#11817491):

Where is your scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js script located? If it is located in your assets directory, then you should initialize the webView giving it the assets directory as baseUrl:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

or

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

You could try to create a simple .js file with a simple function like

```
function dummy(document) { document.write("Hooray it works"); }
```

and try to access the *dummy* function in your html to test if the .js file is included.

Answer (score 2):

I Guess, some javascript functions like prompt and alert (System popups), should be implemented by your code.
A simple guide..,

**1. Create a class Jscalls.java**

```
public class Jscalls {

    Context mContext;
    Jscalls(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void alert(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }    
}
```

**2. In your program add**, `webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Jscalls(this), "Android");`

**3. In html pages**, *instead of `alert("hello")`*, use `Android.alert("hello")`

Hope it works :)

Comment: yes of course, this works. Though we seem to be facing a problem totally different.

Answer (score 1):

You should give full path to load javascript and css for example

```
<link href="http://yourdomain.com/css/my.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: That i did already, problem is somewhere else. Thanks for input.