# MathJax in Android

Tags: java, android, cdn, mathjax

I am trying to display MathJax CDN onto my Android app using WebView. I created a [LaTex code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaMME.png) here. Please help me display this html on my android app.

[Result after Deployement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5m5B.png)

Thanks

Comment: What did you try to resolve this problem?

Comment: I tried using Asset but again I actually want to do it with CDN. Also do you think jqMath would help?

Comment: There should be no difference between CDN and a local version. You are following the code showed in the [getting started](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) section. Try using the working [example](https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-mml.html) first.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a problem, but when I do a Webview at my Android code, it does not show. Says "File not available".

Comment: May [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted#enable_javascript) howto page could help. Did you enable JavaScipt and set the right permissions?

Comment: Yeah I used Internet Permission. Also I tried the sample example you suggested and it goes displayed. But when I use my own LaTex html, it doesnot. This is mine: wq.loadUrl("file:///D:/circleeq.html"); Sample example: wq.loadUrl("https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-mml.html");

Comment: You should your use the Assets folder. Look at [this](http://www.android-examples.com/load-local-html-file-in-webview-on-android/) example.

Comment: I tried the way showed, but doesnot work. I have added a pic on my original question. Please see

Comment: You are giving wrong URL to load the file from assets check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152422/webview-load-html-from-assets-directory)

Comment: @shadygoneinsane So its should be `wq.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/circleeq.html");` in my case right?

Comment: I have written the code in the answer

Comment: Thanks, but my html file consisted of an equation which I did using Latex. I have added a picture of what I was suppose to get, and what I am getting actually.

Comment: Yes it will work as you expected that i am sure :)

Comment: No I am not getting the expected result. Equation is coming in  LaTex syntax. Since I am new user, Stackoverflow doesnot allow me to put two images without 10 reputation.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750657/android-webview-doesnt-load-jquery)  question and the code suggested in the answers. To verify everything else you could put the library also in the assets folder (change the reference in the HTML). Have a good new year ;-)

Comment: Since I am using LaTex in my HTML file so I am using MathJax as `<script type="text/javascript" async 
 src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"> `. Have to figure out what package to import at the libs to make the app, LaTex equation enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the wrong URL for your Assets file

Instead of getting the html file from assets of your app on mobile device you have given the location of your app code on your machine.

so change the URl to this and it will work :

```
 WebView wq;
    wq = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings websettings = wq.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wq.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/circleeq.html");
```

Comment: On deploying it says: `Webpage not available` why so ? Please help

Comment: Check if the Url is proper and file is present in Assets folder